# Windows Store and several other apps missing on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Some apps in my PC suddenly gone missing, pinned app icon becomes blank, and worst is that one of the missing one is Store. Others I have noticed are MSN apps, Mail, Calendar, and Photos, any help how to restore them?

**UPDATE**:
Reinstalling via PowerShell with following command doesn't work:

> Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage
>   -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}

It show lots of error. If there is a way to generate log file please tell me.

**UPDATE**:
Found a documentation from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt185364(v=vs.85).aspx) and after following it, still it doesn't work but it generates a shorter error information:

> Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.2323.4.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\App
>   At D:\Aprianto Nursetiawan\Desktop\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1:35
>   char:2
>   +     Add-AppxPackage -register $PackagePath -DisableDevelopmentMode
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...dleManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage],
>   ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

Comment: Maybe move this question to appropriate site?

Comment: It is already at the appropriate site.  Are you able to use a restore point by chance?  Did you run any commands to remove Cortana or do anything that might explain what basically amounts to removing the `WindowsApps` directory?

Comment: I got a downvote, probably I asked this on a wrong site? Anyway, I removed the Xbox app months ago, and now I want it back, I ran the powershell command to reinstall default Windows 10 apps (the same with UPDATE 1 in my question), but the result is instead of the apps I removed (the Xbox app) to be reinstalled again, it removed some of my apps. including Store.

Comment: Also system restore probably works, but if possible I don't want to use it since the restore point is several days ago and I have installed GBs of applications and driver since then, unless as last resort.

Comment: @Ramhound Hey.. I gave up and asked my friend to take care about it, he restored my PC and reinstall everything I needed with his internet connection. So if you would go ahead and answer with system restore solution I'd accept it, thanks.

Comment: i've found a great solution, please check in [https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings/1525258#1525258](https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings/1525258#1525258)

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the Windows Store Cache:

> 1. Go to the Start Screen or the Windows Modern UI screen
> 2. Type in WSReset.exe
> 3. Click on Run as administrator

[image]

> 4. Reboot, log in, and test.

Comment: Hey. Done running WSReset.exe and restarting, but the Store app still missing? Is this procedure also works in Windows 10?

Comment: It should work in Windows 10. Did you run it as Administrator?
Else take a look at this link: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-store-app-missing-windows-10
try step 1 till 3.

Comment: Yes. I ran it as administrator. I have followed that link, the result is posted in second UPDATE on my question.

Comment: running that got me to an error message from WSReset.exe: "ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches" With further "info": "The application cannot be started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem".
And yes, I can read, but where and how do I reinstall it? Via those powershell scripts? Doesn't work :/..