# After Windows update, notepad app misses its icon. What could be wrong/how to fix this?

Tags: windows-10, icons

After a recent update, notepad app lost its icon: it is not displayed in the corner of the window:

[image]

in the taskbar:

[image]

in the file system and basically everywhere (the screenshot below is for `C:\Windows`)

[image]

What could be wrong and what can I do about this? Notepad is not an [UWP](https://superuser.com/q/1319157/576393) app if I understand correctly (and notepad is the only app that lost its icon as far as I can see); for start menu (I'm using Open Shell) I tried to set the icon manually and it tells that "notepad.exe doesn't contain icons":

[image]

and the list from SHELL32.dll doesn't seem to contain the icon as well:

[image]

(well, I won't make screenshots covering the whole set, but you got the idea)

May be somebody knows where it *should* be located? Could it be located in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` itself? (since I have Programs organized into folders of my liking, I've deleted some folders with links "restored" in Programs by update; but it would be weird to store the icon only there)

Comment: Are the files `\Windows\Notepad.exe` and `\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe` identical? Do you happen to have `signtool.exe` from Windows SDK on the system, and if you do, does `signtool verify /a /v C:\Windows\Notepad.exe` pass the check?

Comment: @grawity yeah, `Windows\System32\Notepad.exe` has an icon, thanks!

Comment: @grawity Actually I had an app to calc hashes, but its "addition" in properties menu is missing for now, so can't check quickly

Comment: I wasn't talking about hashes; without having the exact same Windows build/version at hand, I would have no way to tell if the hash is correct. The signature check however would be able to return "good/bad" all on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the icon cache
by executing the following command

> ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache

for windows 10 use

> ie4uinit.exe -show

Alternatively try [this](https://www.itechtics.com/refresh-icon-cache-without-restarting-windows/) or [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-icon-cache-database-windows-10) tutorial

Comment: thanks but grawity has pointed the right direction: `\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe` does have an icon and it was enough to pick that one

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties of Notepad, click the button of **Change Icon...**.

Enter as file name `%windir%\system32\notepad.exe` and press
<kbd>Enter</kbd> to find your icon.
Click OK twice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the correct settings for Notepad.exe should better be:
Target: %windir%\system32\notepad.exe
Start In: %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
[image]