# Windows 11 Apps Icons Broken

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons

The taskbar can't display my UWP apps (Windows apps like Photo/Media player, but not the apps I installed) properly, as shown:

Taskbar glitch
[image] (This is supposed to be the app "Movie and TV")

This is also the case with my right click menu:
[image: Right click menu glitch] (This is supposed to be "Photo")

However, the Windows start menu and the left-top icon of the opened windows are not affected:
[image: Windows menu]

I've tried deleting icon cache but it won't work. Thank you in advance for helping me out!

(By the way, I'm trying to remove "Create Google ..." from my "create" menu, any ideas about that?
[image: Google Docs])

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings) help in solving the problem?

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! It worked!

Comment: And apologize for asking 2 questions in the same post, won't do that again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

About the *removal of "Create Google ..." from my "create" menu* you can do that.

In the Windows registry, navigate to HKEY_CLASSES and remove the ShellNew subkeys associated with .gdoc, .gsheet, and .gslides file extensions.